# Angular UI Router: Different states with same URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The landing page of my app has two states: `home-public`, `home-logged-in`. Now I want to show both states on the same URL, but let the controller and template depend on the user session (is the user logged in or not?).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could have a base state that controls which state to load, and you could simply have the child stated of that base state not have urls:

```
.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "....",
  controller: function($scope,$state,authSvc) {
     if(authSvc.userIsLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home.loggedin')
     }else{
          $state.go('home.public')
     }
  }
})


.state('home.public', {
  url: "",
  templateUrl: "....",
  controller: function($scope) {
     ...........
  }
})

.state('home.loggedin', {
  url: "",
  templateUrl: "....",
  controller: function($scope) {
     ...........
  }
})
```

Now in the controller of your base state (`home`) you can check if the user is logged in or not, and use `$state.go()` to load an appropriate state.

**EDIT**

As promised, [a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/joXPfnvZxvKbIhCXLxzf?p=preview).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I think it has something to do with the similar URLs. If I comment out one of the sub states, it works.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy, I've used this approach before, let me create a plunk.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is it necessary to define empty url's in the substates. For me, it also works without them.

Comment: Yea, that's not necessary at all, you can just leave them empty.

Comment: This working correct when tag "<div ui-view></div>" exist in template for state "home".

Comment: It doesnt' work for me, but the trick is the url: "", so I add that to the loggedout state,  don't put it under home, and it worked

Comment: The parent and the childs has the same url, Your trick works just because the parent transact to the childs (home -> home.loggedin). If you transact directly to the child from another state (not 'home') it won't work correctly.. ui-router will call onExit of the child state. I couldn't find a solution to this.. even I can't declare a state as 'unactivable' by hitting the url

Comment: @PaoloSanchi you can solve that by making "home" state "abstract: true"

Comment: Using this approach there is issue when refreshing page from some reason both controllers are getting accessed, anyone knows anything about that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if two states can have the same `url`. What i can think can be a viable option would be to define a single state

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  templateUrl: function (stateParams){
    // Implement a logic that select what view from the server should be returned for logged in user and otherwise
    //return 'templateurl';
  }
})
```

I have not tried but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried to do, but it seems that I cannot pass my session or user model to `myApp.Config`, so I cannot build the right logic.

Comment: Have you tried templateProvider which is fully injectable. You can try `<div ng-include='templateurl'></div` in return value. See the example in documentation.