# Open page url in modal on a page (Facebook Photo URLs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

P.S. I am using html5Mode to remove '#' in routing in below scenario [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Consider I have two main pages.One is photos where thumbnails are provided and whose url is `/someSlug/photos`. Other is the url of a single photo '/someSlug/photos/somePhotoId' which shows a bigger view of a particular photo.

My problem is to show the `/someSlug/photos/somePhotoId` page in modal when user clicked on somePhoto thumbnail in photos page (and yes the url should change to `/someSlug/photos/somePhotoId`). But if user access it directly like this `/someSlug/photos/somePhotoId` single photo page should come. I am able to include the single photo template into my modal but facing issues with routing. Not able to change the url while opening the modal to /someSlug/photos/somePhotoId because it opens up new page.

I have two modules for this:
A-> Used and handles routes of photos page
B-> used and handle routes of single photo

Since B single photo template is used in 'A', I have put dependency of 'B' into 'A'. So whenever I try to change the url to /someSlug/photos/somePhotoId while in modal. B's routing overrides the job and open the page. Best example for this is facebook photos. Tried to create a fiddle but its not giving me routing access. Just have a look on facebook photos URL and you will come to know about it. If you needs more inputs, please let me know :)

I am very new to angularJS (Basics->Advanced Stage). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating two states with same URL.

For the state that opens the modal , create a hidden parameter , using `params` option. This is used to find weather the user came from clicking or directly. If user comes by clicking ,then we set a value for the hidden parameter via `ui-sref` and show the modal (using UI Bootstrap's $modal). In case user comes directly to the URL, then we redirect them to the other state with same URL but different template and controller. All this is done inside the `onEnter` function which is called when this state gets opened. As this state has no `template` or `templateUrl` , therefore it doesn't change the view.

The state configuration

```
.state('gallery', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "gallery.html",
    controller: 'galleryCtrl'
})
.state('gallery.photoModal', {
    url: "photo/:id",
    params: {
        fromGallery: null
    },
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
        if ($stateParams.fromGallery === true) {
            console.log('Goes To Modal View');
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: 'modalCtrl',
                size: 'lg'
            }).result.finally(function() {
                $state.go('gallery'); // Parent state
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Goes To Full View');
            $state.go('gallery.photoFull', {
                id: $stateParams.id
            });
        }
    }],
    onExit: ['$modalStack', function($modalStack) {
        // Dismisses Modal if Open , to handle browser back button press
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
    }]
})
.state('gallery.photoFull', {
    url: 'photo/:id',
    templateUrl: "photo.html",
    controller: 'photoCtrl'
})
```

The template for the parent state , from where we click to show the modal

```
<div class="spacing" ui-view>
  <div class="contain" >
    <div ng-repeat='photos in gallery.photos'>
      <a ui-sref="gallery.photoModal({id: photos.id,fromGallery:true})">
        <img ng-src="{{photos.photoURL}}" width="200" height="200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The parent controller , contains dummy data which is used for `ngRepeat`

```
.controller('galleryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.gallery = {
      photos: [{
        photoURL: 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=40&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200',
        id: '1'
      }]
   };
}])
```

The template for the Modal State

```
<div class="spacing">
  <a ng-click="dismiss.modal()" class="pull-right" href>Close</a>
  <img ng-src="{{photo.photoURL}}" width="500" height="500" />
</div>
```

The controller for modal state , contains method to dismiss the modal & dummy data

```
.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.dismiss = {
      modal: function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      }
    };
    $scope.photo = {
      photoURL: 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=80&txt=500%C3%97500&w=500&h=500',
      id: '1'
    };
}])
```

You can check a working example at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wRqwPr?p=preview) , check http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/wRqwPr/#/ to see the changes in URL

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will implement it and let you know abt the results

Comment: Not completely working but very close to achieve the desired result. Some tweaks in my code and it worked :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also please don' remove the plunker. I need it for my future reference :)